bs4_book: how to make search work with static hosting (or disable search bar)
Using bookdown's bs4_book template, running serve_book() launches a local web server, which enables the search bar functionality for searching inside the book.
However, when uploading the folder as a static website, this search bar is unresponsive.
Is there a way to either:

make the search work in a static website? or
hide the search bar?

EDIT: I've found a way to hide the search bar, e.g. adding the following to style.css:
.aa-input{ /* hide search bar */
  visibility: hidden
}

So the remaining question is whether search can be made to work on a static website.
